# Is it time to close or lock a few threads as "historical interest"?

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm looking at [Which are must have lenses for Canon?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5245/which-are-must-have-lenses-for-canon)

There are a few useful answers here, but I think overall it's clear that the intent of the question doesn't bear fruit in the answers. Not to pick on the person who gave this answer personally, but does anyone *really* think that a 50mm f/1.2 lens is a "must have" for the general hobby photography situation described?

I think it might be just best to close this thread (and maybe re-ask it in a more pointed way), but might be more appropriate to use the Historical Lock mechanism (see
[What is a historical lock, and what is it used for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for)).

What do you all think?

Answer (score 2):

I think the question referenced could be a good candidate for a historical lock.  I'm not sure closing is the right move, because it was certainly on topic at the time it was asked.

Also, it seems to meet the criteria: a lot of views, many answers, many upvotes, and there is certainly some information of value there.